# Estructura NOSQL Firebase

Tags: base-de-datos, firebase, nosql

Requiero ayuda para estructurar base de datos en Firebase (NoSQL), en SQL que es relacional si tengo muy claro como realizarlo, pero en bases de datos no relacionales como Firebase no tengo entendido como. Actualmente son 4 tablas:

1. Usuarios (Autenticacion de Firebase)
2. Categorias
3. Subcategorias
4. Entradas

Es de aclarar lo siguiente:

1. Un registro de usuario puede tener muchas categorias con nombres diferentes
2. Un registro de usuario puede tener muchas subcategorias (estás se contendrán dentro de la tabla categorias)
3. Un usuario puede tener muchas entradas
4. Cada entrada puede tener solo una categoria y subcategoria
5. Una categoria puede tener muchas subcategorias
6. Una categorias solo puede tener un usuario

Espero haber sido muy claro, por lo que quisiera saber en JSON o en Firebase como podría realizar esta relaciones o la mejor forma de estructurar la base de datos. Una propuesta o lo que imagina en JSON seria algo como:

```
{
   "usuarios":{
      "1": {
         "email": "Daniel",
         "photoURL": 40,
         "password": 123456,
      },
      "2": {...}
   },
   "categorias":{
      "1":{
         "name": "Wallpapers",
         "createdAt": "18/09/2020",
         "usuarios": {
            "1": true
         },
      },
      "2": {...},
   },
   "subcategorias":{
      "1": {
         "name": "Windows",
         "createdAt": "18/09/2020",
         "categorias": {
            "1": true
         },
      },
      "2": {...}
   },
   "entradas":{
      "1": {
         "type": "inc",
         "value": 10000,
         "createdAt": "18/09/2020",
         "usuarios": {
            "1": true
         },
         "categorias": {
            "1": true,
         },
         "subcategorias": {
            "1": true,
         },
      },
      "2": {...}
   },
}
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Tu pregunta se basa en opiniones. Por otro lado usar un valor numérico como clave (propiedad) para almacenar un documento no es lo más adecuado. Por la estructura que muestras, `usuario` es un gran documento con muchos subdocumentos. Lo mismo para `categorias` y el resto de *tablas*. Usualmente en *noSQL* se habla de colecciones, que no es más que una gran lista (como un Array) de documentos. No manejo Firebase, por lo tanto poco más puedo aportar. Saludos

Comment: Es de aclarar que las claves no son numeros, serían identificadores claves (alfanumericos) auto asignados por firebase. Si tengo entendido que noSQL se referencia a colecciones de documentos, pero en estos casos no sabría como proceder. Agradezco tu comentario y aporte.

Comment: Pues entonces una buena repasada de la [documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model?hl=es) seguro te viene bastante bien. Entiendo que cambiar la visión de los datos cuando vienes de un ambiente *relacional* puede ser complicado, pero con el tiempo te acostumbrarás. Y sobre los campos o identificadores (alfanuméricos o no), sigue siendo un sinsentido almacenar los documentos de esa forma. Un documento válido sería: `{id: <valor>, nombre: <valor>, apellido: <valor>}` y cada documento como el planteado vive en una colección. El campo `id` es el discriminador. Saludos